JavaScript window.close not working, no any responses and result
I would like to popup a winodw with a button and close by another one, here is my code:
The window could be successfully open but cannot close, no any reponses by clicking the button. Is it a browser problem or what?


var newWin;

function openWindow() {
  newWin = window.open('https://www.google.com', '', 'width=400,height=1000');
}

function closeWindow() {
  newWin.close();
}
<button onclick="openWindow()">Open Window</button>
<button onclick="closeWindow()">Close Window</button>




Can't reproduce on Firefox 127.0 (64bit) and Chrome 126.0.6478.62 (64bit) - demo

Which browser are you using?

It could be reference-loss. If you call openWindow multiple times, the ref to the previous window will be lost and you won't be able to close it.
Or the browser does not allow to close it.

Yes, sounds like a comment. Why not just comment this?

so, how to close that open window with a button? can you give me a jsfiddle demo?

 window.close 

is true even after you open a window using script.
Reason for this when you click on close window button it triggers mouse click outside window and the window gets minimized. So the window is null at that moment so your closeWindow function won't get any window to close*

What's your source for this? As stated in the comments I can't reproduce this. I can even move, maximize, minimize the opened window and it still gets closed when clicking the "close window"

"window.close is true even after you open a window using script." - Can you explain this further? Can't see how this is related. OP is not even using the return value or anything
